Как правильно отправить запрос к Telegram через Tdlib с помощью Python
Пытаюсь вызвать метод через auth.checkPhone
документация telegram core
Но все попытки терпят неудачу и я не понимаю почему. Ошибок никаких нет. Но и выполнение функции не производится. В документации написано что метод может вызываться до выполнения входа т.е авторизации.


client_id = _td_create_client_id()

def td_send(query):
    query = json.dumps(query).encode('utf-8')
    _td_send(client_id, query)


def td_receive():
    result = _td_receive(1.0)
    if result:
        result = json.loads(result.decode('utf-8'))
    return result
check_phone_query = {
    '@type': 'checkPhone',
    'phone_number': phone_number,
    '@extra': 1.01234 
}

td_send(check_phone_query)

response = td_receive()
if response:
    if response['@type'] == 'auth.checkedPhone':
        print(f"Phone registered: {response['phone_registered']}")
        print(f"Phone invited: {response['phone_invited']}")
    elif response.get('@type') == 'error':
        print(f"Error occurred: {response['message']} (Code: {response['code']})")
    else:
        print("Unexpected response type:", response)
else:
    print("No response received.")



что я делаю не так и как нужно правильно?
